# Как сделать так чтобы bat ник работал с программой

Tags: bat

Можно ли сделать так чтобы `bat` ник работал самостоятельно сам с программой 
ну например у меня есть скрипт 

`@echo off 
telnet 192.168.1.1`

а как сделать чтобы батник сам смог вводить пароль и логин ??

я пробовал так 
`echo admin`

Но чет не вышло 
Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Способы подключения через BAT существуют, но они не являются особо безопасными.

Итак, для подключения используйте команды вида:

```
echo password | telnet -l username 192.168.1.1
```

Или:

```
telnet -l username 192.168.1.1 <pass.txt
```

Соответственно, *username* - имя пользователя, *password* - пароль, а *password.txt* - файл, содержащий пароль и перенос строки в конце.